# Autofill the values from found columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find two columns by their name in a sheet, viz. Column "**Fruits**" and column "**Vegetables**" and then trying to paste these columns's merged value in a **new column**.

Sheet "**FruitsVege**"

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | New Column | Fruits | Vegetables |
| 2 | Blank | Apple | Spinach |
| 3 | Blank | Orange | Cabbage |

Desired Result in Sheet "**FruitsVege**"

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | New Column | Fruits | Vegetables |
| 2 | AppleSpinach | Apple | Spinach |
| 3 | OrangeCabbage | Orange | Cabbage |

**My code**

```
Sub Merge_B&C()
Dim WrkBk1 As Workbook
Dim WrkBk2 As Workbook
Set WrkBk2 = ActiveWorkbook
Set WrkBk1 = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws2 = WrkBk2.Sheets(1)
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xRgUni As Range
    Dim xFirstAddress As String
    Dim xStr As String
    On Error Resume Next
    
    
    
    ' Insert a column in the beginning
  ws2.Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    
'Search for Fruits Column
    xStr = "Fruits"
    Set xRg = ws2.Range("A1:CA1").Find(xStr, , xlValues, xlWhole, , , True)
    If Not xRg Is Nothing Then
        xFirstAddress = xRg.Address
        Do
            Set xRg = ws2.Range("A1:CA1").FindNext(xRg)
            If xRgUni Is Nothing Then
                Set xRgUni = xRg
            Else
                Set xRgUni = Application.Union(xRgUni, xRg)
            End If
        Loop While (Not xRg Is Nothing) And (xRg.Address <> xFirstAddress)
    End If
    

'Search for Vegetables Column

Dim xRg1 As Range
    Dim xRgUni1 As Range
    Dim xFirstAddress1 As String
    Dim xStr1 As String

    xStr1 = "Vegetables"
    Set xRg1 = ws2.Range("A1:CA1").Find(xStr1, , xlValues, xlWhole, , , True)
    If Not xRg1 Is Nothing Then
        xFirstAddress = xRg1.Address
        Do
            Set xRg1 = ws2.Range("A1:CA1").FindNext(xRg1)
            If xRgUni1 Is Nothing Then
                Set xRgUni1 = xRg1
            Else
                Set xRgUni1 = Application.Union(xRgUni1, xRg1)
            End If
        Loop While (Not xRg1 Is Nothing) And (xRg1.Address <> xFirstAddress)
    End If
    
    
'Select A2
   ws2.Range("A2").Select

'Write A2 = B2&C2 and Autofill
With ws2.Range("a2", Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[xRgUni.Offset(1, 0)]&RC[xRgUni1.Offset(1, 0)]"
        End With

        
End Sub
```

**What I tried** is this, but it pastes the values only and I cannot Autofill for the whole column! It would be great if someone can set me on the right track. Thank you.

```
ws2.Range("A2").Value = ((xRgUni.Offset(1, 0).Value) & (xRgUni1.Offset(1, 0).Value))
```

Comment: Do you have multiple Fruit and Vegetable columns? When you do this "=RC[xRgUni.Offset(1, 0)]&RC[xRgUni1.Offset(1, 0)]" everything inside the quotes will appear literally in the cell.

Comment: @SJR No, I don't have multiple columns. In sheet "FruitsVege", I have these two columns only. I need to Make column A value = B&C. Eg. A2 = B2&C2 and autofill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an outline approach which hopefully you can adapt.

```
Sub x()
  
Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range

Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

With Rows(1)
    Set r1 = .Find(What:="Fruits", Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    Set r2 = .Find(What:="Vegetables", Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not r1 Is Nothing And Not r2 Is Nothing Then
        Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, r1.Column).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=" & r1.Offset(1).Address(0, 0) & " & " & r2.Offset(1).Address(0, 0)
       'hyphen below
       'Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, r1.Column).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=" & r1.Offset(1).Address(0, 0) & " & ""-"" & " & r2.Offset(1).Address(0, 0)
    End If
End With
     
End Sub
```

Comment: I wanted to add a hyphen between B2 and C2 then should I make it like this ?  Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, r1.Column).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=" & r1.Offset(1).Address(0, 0) & " & " &"-" " & " & r2.Offset(1).Address(0, 0)

Comment: Also , how do I add other formulas like  "=YEAR(RC[-61])*100+WEEKNUM(RC[-61],21)"     ? Thank you

Comment: I've added a line above in the code, not sure from your comment.

Comment: I understood now! So for all other formulas, I just add the formula element in quotation marks. For eg. "&" "Year"  ! Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes just remember to double-up quotes inside VBA if the formula has quotes in it.

Comment: I am trying to find a "New column" by its name and creating an another empty column next to it and then trying to copy values in it. But I am facing syntax errors in the last line. I modified code  Set r3 = .Find(What:="New Column", Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not r1 Is Nothing And Not r2 Is Nothing And Not r3 Is Nothing Then 
Range(Cells.(r3.offset(1,0)) & Cells(Rows.Count, r1.Column).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=" & r1.Offset(1).Address(0, 0) & " & ""-"" & " & r2.Offset(1).Address(0, 0)

Comment: I think this should be a new question.

Comment: Hi, I have created a new question! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66763913/select-the-last-filled-cell-from-the-referenced-column Thank you

Comment: Hi again, Sorry I tried to adapt your tips to ammend the other formulas, but facing syntax errors. Can you tell me what wrong I have written. I have created a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66797127/how-to-ammend-the-excel-formula-in-vba-code   Thank you