# Select the last filled cell from the referenced column

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find a last empty column and writing the column name. The code find this new column by it's name and selects the second cell and paste the values from Column B and Column C till exceldown. But, the code fills all the blank cells of column D with hyphen "-". I want to somehow define the last filled cell and paste till last filled cell of Column B only. I am facing syntax errors. Any lead how do I achieve it? Thank you!

Sheet "**FruitsVege**"

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Category | Fruits | Vegetables |
| 2 | Blank | Apple | Spinach |
| 3 | Blank | Orange | Cabbage |

Desired Result in Sheet "**FruitsVege**"

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Category | Fruits | Vegetables | FruitsVege |
| 2 | Blank | Apple | Spinach | Apple-Spinach |
| 3 | Blank | Orange | Cabbage | Orange-Cabbage |

**The Code**

```
Sub Merge_FV ()
  
Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, r3 As Range

Dim emptyColumn As Long


'find empty Column (actually cell in Row 1)'
emptyColumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
If emptyColumn > 1 Then
emptyColumn = emptyColumn + 1
End If

 Cells(1, emptyColumn).Value = "FruitsVege"

With Rows(1)
    Set r1 = .Find(What:="Fruits", Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    Set r2 = .Find(What:="Vegetables", Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    Set r3 = .Find(What:="FruitsVege", Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
     If Not r1 Is Nothing And Not r2 Is Nothing And Not r3 Is Nothing Then
         r3.Offset(1, 0).Select
         Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Formula = "=" & r1.Offset(1).Address(0, 0) & " & ""-"" & " & r2.Offset(1).Address(0, 0)
    End If
End With

     
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried to adapt my answer to your previous question but I was effectively doing the same?

Comment: @SJR Yes , I tried to to adapt your answer to my previous question. As I said, I have to copy the values from B and C to D , so I modified this line Range(Cells.(r3.offset(1,0)) & Cells(Rows.Count, r1.Column).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=" & r1.Offset(1).Address(0, 0) & " & ""-"" & " & r2.Offset(1).Address(0, 0) . Added r3 in Range, but throws an error. So I thought of using another approach,  find a column name, select the offset cell and paste the data. But now , I am not able to fill the data till the last filled row! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested but should work - I have just amended the formula line. You need to find the last row by working up from the bottom of the sheet, and there is no need to select anything.

```
Sub Merge_FV()
  
Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, r3 As Range

Dim emptyColumn As Long, LastRow As Long

'find empty Column (actually cell in Row 1)'
emptyColumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
If emptyColumn > 1 Then
    emptyColumn = emptyColumn + 1
End If

Cells(1, emptyColumn).Value = "FruitsVege"

With Rows(1)
    Set r1 = .Find(What:="Fruits", Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    Set r2 = .Find(What:="Vegetables", Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    Set r3 = .Find(What:="FruitsVege", Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not r1 Is Nothing And Not r2 Is Nothing And Not r3 Is Nothing Then
        LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, r1.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        r3.Offset(1, 0).Resize(LastRow - 1).Formula = "=" & r1.Offset(1).Address(0, 0) & " & ""-"" & " & r2.Offset(1).Address(0, 0)
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this code, but does not work! It copies only two rows and pastes in the new created column. And it deletes the new column header name, and pastes values from the header cell!

Comment: Oops, amended above.

Comment: The code makes it happen!!! Once again, thank you! Have a nice time! :)