# How to ammend the excel formula in vba code?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two formulas
The original formulas in Excel sheet are:

1. `=YEAR(G2)*100+WEEKNUM(G2;21)`
2. `=TEXT(G2;"JJJJ-MM")`

In VBA they becomes:

1. `= "=YEAR(RC[-58])*100+WEEKNUM(RC[-58],21)"`
2. `= "=TEXT(RC[-59],""JJJJ-MM"")"`

G2 is a second cell from column `C_Date`

The following code creates a new column `Due CW` then try to find column `C_Date` and selects a second cell in it. I am trying to ammend the above VBA formulas in this code but facing syntax errors.

It would be great if someone puts me on the right track!

```
Sub Due CW()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, r3 As Range
    Dim emptyColumn As Long, LastRow As Long
    
    'find empty Column (actually cell in Row 1)
    emptyColumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    If emptyColumn > 1 Then
        emptyColumn = emptyColumn + 1
    End If
    
    Cells(1, emptyColumn).Value = "Due KW"
    
    With Rows(1)
        Set r1 = .Find(What:="C_Date", Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        Set r3 = .Find(What:="Due CW", Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not r1 Is Nothing And Not r2 Is Nothing And Not r3 Is Nothing Then
            LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, r1.Column).End(xlUp).Row
            r3.Offset(1, 0).Resize(LastRow - 1).Formula = "=" & "YEAR" &(r1.offset(1,0).Address(0, 0))&"*"&"100"&"+"&"WEEKNUM"&(r1.offset(1,0).Address(0, 0),21)"
                                                           
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: The brackets that are currently around the cell addresses need to be within the quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue with the quotes in the very end of the following line and the parenthesis should be within the quotes too:

```
r3.Offset(1, 0).Resize(LastRow - 1).Formula = "=" & "YEAR(" & r1.Offset(1, 0).Address(0, 0) & ")*" & "100" & "+" & "WEEKNUM(" & r1.Offset(1, 0).Address(0, 0) & ",21)"
```

you can easily test it like

```
Debug.Print "=" & "YEAR(" & r1.Offset(1, 0).Address(0, 0) & ")*" & "100" & "+" & "WEEKNUM(" & r1.Offset(1, 0).Address(0, 0) & ",21)"
```

to verify the result, this should now resolve to:

```
=YEAR(ADDRESS)*100+WEEKNUM(ADDRESS),21)
```

You can even write this shorter for better readability by concatenating the strings directly like:

```
r3.Offset(1, 0).Resize(LastRow - 1).Formula = "=YEAR(" & r1.Offset(1, 0).Address(0, 0) & ")*100+WEEKNUM(" & r1.Offset(1, 0).Address(0, 0) & ",21)"
```

Comment: @Peh I tried your code, it runs without any syntax errors but it does not do anything. The Due_CW column remains blank! Thank you

Comment: @Goku probably `If Not r1 Is Nothing And Not r2 Is Nothing And Not r3 Is Nothing Then` is not `True` then. Go through your code step by step using F8 and see if your formula code is getting executed at all. `r2` is never set to anything so it is definitly `Nothing`. You are only using `r1` and `r3`.

Comment: @Peh It works! Thanks a lot for the tip and the direction! Have a nice time! :)